# How can I handle a hover the Polymer way without external libraries?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I figured I would need to do something like:

`<li on-mouseover="{{ myHoverHandler }}">blah</li>` because handling clicks looks like this:

`<li on-click="{{ myClickHandler }}">blah</li>`

I've tried using the way shown in the documentation here: [declarative event mapping](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping) , but `on-mouseenter` and `on-mouseover` aren't working as expected.

I'm also having trouble passing parameters to my handlers, but that's a different story.

Comment: How should the hovers be handled, specifically?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I'm saying that my handle never gets called. It actually gets called when I click the element right before the click event happens.

Comment: @RobertHarvey this has nothing to do with using pure JavaScript. I am trying to use Polymers declarative event binding. And I can't get my `on-mouseover` or `on-mouseenter` to work.

Comment: You could have been a bit clearer about that.  What prevents you from using Javascript or jQuery?  Does Polymer force you to use only Polymer bindings?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm trying to learn Polymer and do things without any external dependencies. As to why I can't do it in pure JavaScript: I could, but again I'm looking for the Polymer way of doing it. Since it allows for declarative event binding I'd like to keep all my events handled in this way.

Comment: Have you looked at [Pointer Events](https://github.com/polymer/PointerEvents)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have briefly, but according to the documentation I shouldn't need to use that. It may be a good idea, but I just want to understand why the others aren't working.

Comment: The documentation there describes some compelling reasons for using them.  You did say that you wanted the Polymer way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Technically the polymer way is to use declarative event mapping. Using PointerEvents would be doing it the Platform way which is fine, but that isn't answering the question I asked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`on-mouseover` and `on-mouseout` are correct, here's a demo as a `Stack Snippet`:

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.3/platform.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.3/polymer.js"></script>

<my-app></my-app>
  
<polymer-element name='my-app'>
  <template>
    <button on-mouseover='{{onHovered}}' 
            on-mouseout='{{onUnhovered}}'>
      A humble button
    </button>
    <div>
      hovered: {{hovered}}
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-app', {
      hovered: false,
      onHovered: function() {
        this.hovered = true;
      },
      onUnhovered: function() {
        this.hovered = false;
      }
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

It's possible that your element doesn't have a `myHoverHandler` property. Perhaps there's a typo?

As for whether to use Polymer event binding vs other methods, you can absolutely do this with vanilla js or jquery or whatever. Polymer handles a bit of the busy work, like making sure that the event handler is registered in conditional and repeated templates, binding `this` to the element which is usually what you want, and deregistering the handlers when their elements are removed from the DOM. There are times though when doing it manually makes sense too though.

Comment: Thank Peter! This is exactly what I had except that I was doing all my development in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/). I moved my code to a JS Bin and it seemed to work as expected. I appreciate your help.

Comment: One last addition. I was able to get it working in Plunker again I just needed to refresh the page.

Comment: Just as an update to Polymer 1.0 users. The new syntax uses `on-mousout="onHovered"` instead of `{{onHovered}}`

Answer (score 5):

Actually it should be

```
<button on-mouseover='onHovered' 
        on-mouseout='onUnhovered'>
```

without the curly braces. Also, you don't need to pass in the properties if you need to use them in the event handler function.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to react to hover on the **host**-Component itself, you should **use listeners**:

```
<dom-module id="hoverable-component">
  <template>

    <div>Hoverable Component</div>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'hoverable-component',

      listeners: {
        mouseover: '_onHostHover',
        mouseout: '_onHostUnhover',
      },

      _onHostHover: function(e){
        console.debug('hover');  
      },

      _onHostUnhover: function(e){
        console.debug('unhover');  
      },

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```