# How to dynamically change CSS in polymer?

Tags: html, polymer

I have a polymer element which is a stack of images that need to expand and reveal each of the images upon hovering on the stack. It's supposed to look like this if left untouched:

[image] And upon hovering, the stack would expand vertically.

The code for the element is (`do-profile-pic` is another element that puts each image down):

```
<polymer-element name="do-profile-pic-stack" attributes="images">
    <template>
    <style>...</style>
      <div class="stack-container"
           on-mouseover='{{onHovered}}'
           on-mouseout='{{onUnhovered}}'>
        <template repeat="{{picture, i in images}}">
          <div class="stack-img-container"
               /* the stack is angled so bit of every image is visible */
               style="top: {{5 * i}}; z-index: {{10 - i}}">
            <do-profile-pic imgurl="{{picture.url}}" showtime="false">
            </do-profile-pic>
          </div>
        </template>
      </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('do-profile-pic-stack', {
      images: [],
      ...
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Now i've looked around, and there seem to be two ways to do this. One is to use the polymer selectors. The other is to use user event methods. I'm not using any of these methods to achieve the default angled layout (comment above). To expand the stack vertically, i'll have to play with positioning and layout, but i cannot seem to think of a good way to implement the this.

The polymer selectors appear complicated.
Programmatically, it looks like playing with HTMLElement will be required. I can do that, but angular-js handles this much better. So is there a better way to go about this that i might be mssing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change appearance on mouse-over I think you can go with a pure CSS solution with two sets of styles one normal and one for mouse-over.

```
stack-img-container {
  // normal style here
}

stack-img-container:hover {
  // mouse-over style
  // overrides and extends normal style
}
```

and put it in your style tag (instead of the dots `...`).

Comment: The style for the container is being generated by the template repeat loop to angle the stack using data binding and the `style` attribute.
The problem with above method is that that class selectors have lower priority than the style attribute. Also, each image requires different layout positioning than the one above it. Above method will apply the style uniformly to all the images. Perhaps using hard-coded classes is the solution?

Comment: I would prefer the way to add classes dynamically. You can use CSSs `calc()` for individually positioning like you do in the `style` attribute. Can you please add more details to your question about what should happen on mouse-over and for which mouse-over (which element).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to change class dynamically.

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.3/platform.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.3/polymer.js"></script>

<my-app></my-app>
  
<polymer-element name='my-app'>
  <template>
     <style>
       .hovered {
         background-color:red;
       }
     </style>
    <span on-mouseenter='{{onHover}}' 
            on-mouseleave='{{onUnhover}}'>
      Mouse over me, please.
    </span>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-app', {

      onHover: function(e) {
        e.srcElement.classList.add('hovered'); 
      },

      onUnhover: function(e) {
        e.srcElement.classList.remove('hovered');
      }
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Notes:

- [Event.srcElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement) is not standard will and not work for every user.
- The standard way to reference an element within an Polymer element is the [Polymer.Base $$(slctr)](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-$$):

  this.$$('span').classList.add('hovered');

  It works in my project, but not in this snippet.
- The code above was copied and edited from [Peter Burns'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101/peter-burns) code snippet from [How can I handle a hover the Polymer way without external libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24744938/1086664)
- Curly braces around onHover in the event handler shouldn't be necessary, however, they don't work otherwise in this snippet. Not sure if it's because of the version of Polymer used. I tried to link to the latest but it failed.
- Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/tylerama/pen/nLFHt) of changing class dynamically with plain javascript.